# Can't save .vb file then just "reload" Chrome on localhost with VS2017

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

For 15+ years across whatever VS version I used the "create website" template, edited in VS, then had a full version of IIS running on my (same) dev machine so when I say wrote "response.write("test this out")" in .vb file I could just save it and ....refresh my browser. And it took like....one second.

NOW....with VS 2017 it doesn't make it easy to start a "new website" although it is possible. So I chose "Web Application" like it wants me to. BUT (HERE is the problem I'm talking about =>)...if I make any .vb changes, it won't refresh in local-IIS until I Build/Rebuild the page which takes a Lot of time.

Yes I have switched to "starting it" in IIS. Doesn't matter. I still need to build or re-build for any .vb changes to take effect. aspx (html) changes work fine, I can just "refresh" but not code changes. Is it because somehow VS applications are compiled into a .dll or something? I cannot believe developers are recompiling every time they want to see any changes.

How do I do this? The way I've always used makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No one answered. I'm told this is the answer. So really no answer but what I said is indeed true.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx